# STM32F103 memory addressing

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded, stm32f10x, st-link

I have written my code for STM32F103C8T6 board in Keil using the adequate startup files. I wrote directly to the memory addresses using information from the datasheet but the ST-Link upload seems to upload the hex file to the wrong addresses for example:

```
GPIOA = 0x4001 0800
```

This is according to the STM datasheet. But ST-Link shows the device data range from:

```
0x0800 0000 to 0x0800 03d4.
```

My code is a simple program to blink the LED at portA1. I connected the LED across a 10k resistor. Why is STM assigning the wrong addresses when I used pointers to specify the memory locations, or could there be any other mistakes. Code below.

```
void delay(int a);

int main(void)
{
    unsigned int* GPIO_A;
    GPIO_A = (unsigned int*)0x40010800 ; // Assigning GPIOA to the correct memory location

    unsigned int* GPIO_A_CRL;
    GPIO_A_CRL = GPIO_A + 0x00 ; // Assigning GPIO_A_CRL to the correct memory location

    /*unsigned int* GPIO_A_IDR;
    GPIO_A_IDR = GPIO_A + 0X08 ; // Assigning GPIO_A_IDR to the correct memory location  */

    unsigned int* GPIO_A_BSRR;
    GPIO_A_BSRR = GPIO_A + 0X10 ; // Assigning GPIO_A_BSRR to the correct memory location

    unsigned int* GPIO_A_BRR;
    GPIO_A_BRR = GPIO_A + 0X14 ; // Assigning GPIO_A_BSRR to the correct memory   location

    unsigned int* RCC_APB2ENR;
    RCC_APB2ENR = (unsigned int*)(0x40021000 + 0X18) ; // Assigning                RCC_APB2ENR to the correct memory location

    *RCC_APB2ENR = 0X04; // Set clock for GPIOA

    *GPIO_A_CRL = 0X00008888 ; // Defining pin modes for GPIO_A_CRL

    while(1)  // infinite loop
    {
        *GPIO_A_BSRR = 0X00000002;  // Set bit 1 to 1
        delay(2); // delay
        *GPIO_A_BRR = 0x00000002;  // reset bit 1 to reset value(0)
        delay(2); // delay
    }
}

void delay(int a)
{
    long b = a*1000000;

    for(int i=0;i<b;i++)
    {
        int c = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: It could make life a lot easier if you include "stm32f10x.h" which comes with keil. The defines are in there.

Comment: yeah. But I want to do it the hard way first, could there be anything wrong with the code

Comment: Code at 0x08000000, GPIO port at 0x40010800. What's the problem with that?

Comment: "but the ST-Link upload seems to upload the hex file to the wrong addresses for example" - No, the *program code* **must** be uploaded to FLASH memory. The instructions in the program can then access any memory/IO address they want. It's like asking why your audio player gets installed on the harddisk and not on the soundcard.

Comment: By the way, is your LED blinking as desired?

Comment: (10k may be a little much. Try 0.5-1k *in series* with the LED.)

Comment: no, the led is not blinking, And even without a resistor it still didnt blink

Answer (score 0):

Check the memory map on the data sheet.  Peripherals are at addresses beginning at `0x40000000`. `0x08000000` is the beginning of Flash (code) memory.

Comment: i have crosschecked and the addresses i selected are right

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem?

Comment: when trying to debug , i get unable to address target resource, illegal address 0x08000000 . And code doesnt work

Comment: Hmm... 0x08000000 is the location of the vector table; it's not an illegal address.  Are you able to connect the debugger and load the program?  Can you view memory?   I'm not familiar with Keil tools.

Comment: yes, but the debugger keeps returning unable to access address

Comment: What are you attempting when it returns the message unable to access address?

Comment: Just attempting to run the code on the processor to blink an LED. it displays the error immediately i enter debug mode

Answer (score -1):

You could have had the wrong address for gpioa.

Comment: I have crosschecked again the addresses are correct .

Comment: Well then a few more possibilities: 1. Thee chip doesn't follow the datasheet. 2. The compiler is faulty. 3. The debuger and software is faulty. 4. Operator error. You can estimate their likely hood and rule them out one at a time.

Comment: when tryimng to debug , i get unable to address target resource, illegal address 0x08000000

Comment: It confirms the issue is operator oriented. Take a loop at the data sheet and check how memory space is organized